# Непонятная ошибка синтаксиса в PHP

Tags: php, syntax

Код:

```
<?php

const SECRET_KEY = 'ek9ghdofzwnifX0=';

$billPayments = new Qiwi\Api\BillPayments(SECRET_KEY);

?>
```

Выходит в консоли:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'and' (T_LOGICAL_AND), expecting end of file in C:\Users\terli\Desktop\php7.4.1\php.ini-development on line 178

Куда выводит ссылка:

This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between  tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It is generally recommended that  should be used and that this feature should be disabled, as enabling it may result in issues when generating XML documents, however this remains supported for backward compatibility reasons. Note that this directive does not control the <?= shorthand tag, which can be used regardless of this directive.

Comment: Попробуйте $billPayments = 'Qiwi\Api\BillPayments(SECRET_KEY)';

Comment: не сработало, все также

Comment: В ошибке ясно сказано где проблема - файл php.ini-development, строка 178. Её в студию!

Comment: Последнее это и есть оно

Comment: Вы пишете PHP код в файле для его конфигурации???

Comment: Ошибка заключается в неправильном использовании логического оператора `and` нужно посмотреть указанную в ошибке строку на этот предмет

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Не знаю где, но хтмл благополучно выводится на локалхосте

Comment: @Daniil Loban это строчка в документации, которая последняя

Comment: @MarkKurbanov не совсем понял, о какой строчке идет речь? об указанной в ошибке?

Comment: @Daniil Loban последнее и есть строчка 178

Comment: тогда ошибка где-то выше, я бы проверял случаи где есть `and` возможно дело даже не в этом операторе но поблизости с ним

Comment: `$a = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id"; AND account != 1";  ` пример строки вызывающий подобную ошибку но тут все проще ошибка в `";` в центре строки

Comment: @Daniil Loban весь код выше, абсолютно весь

Comment: значит ошибка в модулях Qiwi